# fetch date and covert into weekday

Tags: bash, awk

i have data below in csv

```
Date
2022-06-09 22:30:20
2022-06-10 15:55:21
2022-06-11 00:34:05
2022-06-11 19:51:52
2022-06-13 11:34:10
2022-06-15 03:59:54
2022-06-18 16:13:20
2022-06-19 00:24:21
2022-06-19 00:25:36
2022-06-19 00:25:36
2022-06-19 00:25:49
```

i required output in 2 fields as weekday and shift time, if hh:mm is between 7:30AM to 7:30PM it should be print as morning, remaining will be print as Night.

```
date                |   Weekday     |   Shift
--------------------------------------------------------------              
09-06-2022 22:30    |   Thursday    |   Night
10-06-2022 15:55    |   Friday      |   Morning
11-06-2022 00:34    |   Saturday    |   Night
11-06-2022 19:51    |   Saturday    |   Night
13-06-2022 11:34    |   Monday      |   Morning
15-06-2022 03:59    |   Wednesday   |   Night
18-06-2022 16:13    |   Saturday    |   Morning
19-06-2022 00:24    |   Sunday      |   Night
19-06-2022 00:25    |   Sunday      |   Night
19-06-2022 00:25    |   Sunday      |   Night
19-06-2022 00:25    |   Sunday      |   Night
```

I tried with below command to get weekdays and facing difficulties in shift column please help

```
date --date="$dates" +%A
```

Comment: Do you want to use `awk` or `bash`?

Comment: awk would be fine @RenaudPacalet san.

Comment: Consider using the word "Day" instead of "Morning". Morning is only the time of day before noon. Day vs Night makes much more sense for your data than Morning vs Night plus shift work is usually categorized as dayshift vs nightshift.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```bash
gawk 'function dayofweek(time) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       gsub(/[:-]/, " ", time)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       return strftime("%A", mktime(time));                                                                                                                                                                                                      
     }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     BEGIN { OFS="," }                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     NR == 1 { print "Date", "Weekday", "Shift"; next }                                                                                                                                                                                          
     {
       print substr($0, 0, length($0) - 3), dayofweek($0), $2 >= "07:30:00" && $2 <= "19:30:00" ? "Morning" : "Night"
     }' input.csv
```

produces

```
Date,Weekday,Shift
2022-06-09 22:30,Thursday,Night
2022-06-10 15:55,Friday,Morning
2022-06-11 00:34,Saturday,Night
2022-06-11 19:51,Saturday,Night
2022-06-13 11:34,Monday,Morning
2022-06-15 03:59,Wednesday,Night
2022-06-18 16:13,Saturday,Morning
2022-06-19 00:24,Sunday,Night
2022-06-19 00:25,Sunday,Night
2022-06-19 00:25,Sunday,Night
2022-06-19 00:25,Sunday,Night
```

from your input.

It trims the seconds from the date, uses GNU awk specific functions `mktime()` and `strftime()` to get the weekday from the time, and finally just compares the hours portion to the desired range to see if it's morning or night.

Answer (score 0):

> fetch date and covert into weekday

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` context be

```
Date
2022-06-09 22:30:20
2022-06-10 15:55:21
2022-06-11 00:34:05
2022-06-11 19:51:52
2022-06-13 11:34:10
2022-06-15 03:59:54
2022-06-18 16:13:20
2022-06-19 00:24:21
2022-06-19 00:25:36
2022-06-19 00:25:36
2022-06-19 00:25:49
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="-| |:"}NR==1{print "Date","Weekday"}NR>1{t=mktime($1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6);print $0,strftime("%A",t)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Date Weekday
2022-06-09 22:30:20 Thursday
2022-06-10 15:55:21 Friday
2022-06-11 00:34:05 Saturday
2022-06-11 19:51:52 Saturday
2022-06-13 11:34:10 Monday
2022-06-15 03:59:54 Wednesday
2022-06-18 16:13:20 Saturday
2022-06-19 00:24:21 Sunday
2022-06-19 00:25:36 Sunday
2022-06-19 00:25:36 Sunday
2022-06-19 00:25:49 Sunday
```

Explanation: firstly I inform GNU `AWK` that field separator is `-` or   (space) or `:`, then for 1st line I print header, for all lines after 1st I use [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), `mktime` converts string like `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS` into timestamp (number of seconds since start of epoch), then I use `strftime` to convert said variable into string, `%A` denotes full weekday name.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` (tested with GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
  sep = sprintf("%41s", " ")
  gsub(/ /, "-", sep);
  printf("%-19s | %-9s | %-10s\n%s\n", "Day", "Weekday", "Shift", sep)
  mmin = 7 * 3600 + 30 * 60
  mmax = 19 * 3600 + 30 * 60
}
NR > 1 {
  dt = $0
  gsub(/-|:/, " ", dt)
  s = mktime(dt)
  dt0 = $1 " 00 00 00"
  gsub(/-/, " ", dt0)
  s0 = mktime(dt0)
  d = s - s0
  shift = (d > mmin && d < mmax) ? "Morning" : "Night"
  printf("%-19s | %-9s | %s\n", $0, strftime("%A", s), shift)
}' file
Day                 | Weekday   | Shift     
-----------------------------------------
2022-06-09 22:30:20 | Thursday  | Night
2022-06-10 15:55:21 | Friday    | Morning
2022-06-11 00:34:05 | Saturday  | Night
2022-06-11 19:51:52 | Saturday  | Night
2022-06-13 11:34:10 | Monday    | Morning
2022-06-15 03:59:54 | Wednesday | Night
2022-06-18 16:13:20 | Saturday  | Morning
2022-06-19 00:24:21 | Sunday    | Night
2022-06-19 00:25:36 | Sunday    | Night
2022-06-19 00:25:36 | Sunday    | Night
2022-06-19 00:25:49 | Sunday    | Night
```

`mmin` is `7:30` AM in seconds. `mmax` is 7:30 PM in seconds. `dt` is the input date - time with all `-` and `:` replaced by a space (this is the input format of `mktime`). `s` is `dt` converted to seconds since Epoch using `mktime`. `dt0` and `s0` are the same as `dt`and `s` but at `00:00:00`. `d` is the time in seconds since `00:00:00`. The rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  NR==1{
    printf "%-16s | %-9s | %s\n", "Date","Weekday","Shift"; next   
  }
  {
    "date -d \"" $0 "\" \"+%d-%m-%Y %H:%M | %A\"" | getline d
    gsub(/:/, "", $2); t=int($2)
    printf "%-28s | %s\n", d ,(t > 73000 && t < 193000) ? "Morning" : "Night"
  }' file.csv

Date             | Weekday   | Shift
09-06-2022 22:30 | Thursday  | Night
10-06-2022 15:55 | Friday    | Morning
11-06-2022 00:34 | Saturday  | Night
11-06-2022 19:51 | Saturday  | Night
13-06-2022 11:34 | Monday    | Morning
15-06-2022 03:59 | Wednesday | Night
18-06-2022 16:13 | Saturday  | Morning
19-06-2022 00:24 | Sunday    | Night
19-06-2022 00:25 | Sunday    | Night
19-06-2022 00:25 | Sunday    | Night
19-06-2022 00:25 | Sunday    | Night
```

Answer (score 0):

With text and string and csv support, `ruby` is my go to for such projects:

```
ruby -r csv -e '
options={ :headers=>true, :converters=>:date_time}
def d_or_n(dt)
    t=dt.strftime( "%H%M%S%N" )
    st=DateTime.new(2000,1,1,7,30).strftime( "%H%M%S%N" )
    et=DateTime.new(2000,1,1,19,30).strftime( "%H%M%S%N" )
    t >= st && t <= et ? "Day" : "Night"
end

cols=[18,12,7]
fmt="%*s|%*s|%*s\n"
printf(fmt,cols[0],"Date".center(cols[0]),
        cols[1],"Weekday".center(cols[1]), cols[2], "Shift".center(cols[2]))
printf("-"*(cols.sum+2)+"\n")
inp=CSV.parse($<.read, **options).to_a
inp[1..].each{|r| printf(fmt, cols[0], r[0].strftime("%d-%m-%Y %R "), 
                              cols[1], r[0].strftime("%A "), 
                              cols[2], d_or_n(r[0])) }
' dates.csv
```

Prints:

```
       Date       |  Weekday   | Shift 
---------------------------------------
 09-06-2022 22:30 |   Thursday |  Night
 10-06-2022 15:55 |     Friday |    Day
 11-06-2022 00:34 |   Saturday |  Night
 11-06-2022 19:51 |   Saturday |  Night
 13-06-2022 11:34 |     Monday |    Day
 15-06-2022 03:59 |  Wednesday |  Night
 18-06-2022 16:13 |   Saturday |    Day
 19-06-2022 00:24 |     Sunday |  Night
 19-06-2022 00:25 |     Sunday |  Night
 19-06-2022 00:25 |     Sunday |  Night
 19-06-2022 00:25 |     Sunday |  Night
```

Answer (score 0):

using `system()` is far more light-weight than a `getline` :

```
{m,g}awk '($++NF=substr("SunMonTueWedThuFriSat",1+3 * \
                 system("exit \140 gdate -d\42"($_)" UTC-4\42 +%w \140"), 3))  \
          ($++NF=substr("MorngNight",6^($2~/^(2|0[0-6]|07:[0-2]|19:[^0-2])/),5))

2022-06-09 22:30:20 Thu Night
2022-06-10 15:55:21 Fri Morng
2022-06-11 00:34:05 Sat Night
2022-06-11 19:51:52 Sat Night
2022-06-13 11:34:10 Mon Morng
2022-06-15 03:59:54 Wed Night
2022-06-18 16:13:20 Sat Morng
2022-06-19 00:24:21 Sun Night
2022-06-19 00:25:36 Sun Night
2022-06-19 00:25:36 Sun Night
2022-06-19 00:25:49 Sun Night
```